# Record the time/date of a post meta field change WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So I have a post meta field that has two values, true or false. It is defaulted at false, and it'll automatically change to true when an event occurs.

Anyway, is it possible to create another meta field that records the exact time that this change occurs? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Pleae provide more info: specify the place where events occures. Front-end(theme/plugin)/back-end?

Comment: The field is called "Already Aired". It's checked true when another custom post type post is created. That custom post type post has a meta field called "parent ID". Whichever parent ID is located in that field, that post will have it's "Already Aired" turned to true from false.

Comment: Here is the function. Formidable is used in the front end. 

http://pastebin.com/wDL3utHh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well without modifying wordpress core or overriding the `update_field()` function in your theme functions.php you cant get in a smooth way the time when a record has been added to the database.

But what can i advice to you:

1) If your application highly depends on seconds:milliseconds when post_meta has been modified, you should use advanced technique: **database transactions**.

2) If your application are fine with a small delay between writing up 1st meta and the second just add it with [add_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) right below the `update_field()` performed

p.s If you think that overriding the function with functions.php is the way you prefer just ping me a comment, i'll try to help you with by editing the post.

Cheers!

**EDIT**

Right after your manipulation with allready_aired field performed

```
    $alreadyAired = get_field('already_aired', $episodeID);

    if (get_field('already_aired', $episodeID) == "no") {
        update_field('field_28', "yes", $episodeID);
    }
```

you can use [add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) function in a way like this:

```
    $alreadyAired = get_field('already_aired', $episodeID);

    if (get_field('already_aired', $episodeID) == "no") {
        update_field('field_28', "yes", $episodeID);
    }

    add_post_meta($episodeID, 'NEW_TIMESTAMP_FIELD', time(), true);
```

Then, you can call this NEW_TIMESTAMP_FIELD and use in a way you like (echo formatted date-string, compare 2 dates, etc.

Please note the 4th parameter of add_post_meta function. This one tell you that this field is unique and considering that app_post_meta does not affect "Update" actions, this bundle wont let this field get modified in the second time.

Comment: I just need the time recorded when the first post triggers the automation. The time can be similar to how post date works. I believe post date records up to minutes. I guess adding seconds wouldn't be bad at all. A little delay is not going to be a worry. I just need this to be recorded the first time the trigger happens. If it's recorded, then the next time it happens, it shouldn't change the original value.

Comment: Please see my edits below. Hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks I guess a little if condition added won't be too bad something like 

if meta value is empty, only then addpost meta, if not then skip it.

Comment: For some reason at the moment, the time it's recording is 0. I'm using a number meta field by the way.

Comment: Hm, check out if time() return you current timestamp (make an echo). Then you shoud be sure if add_post_meta create an additional field in database. What do you mean under "number meta field". More code please

Comment: It's basically a meta field. Disregard the number thing. Anyway, sometimes it's recording the right time, and sometimes it just records 0

The code is basically copy pasted from what you've posted.